# Custom Keras loss function with calculations involving both Placeholder and constant Tensor objects

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to write a custom loss function for a Keras network.
In this function, the result depends not only on *y_actual* and *y_pred*, but also on some other value that I extract from database using the value of *y_actual*. 
I wrote the following function. In this function, I want to involve the label of *y_actual* that I retrieve from database in the loss calculation.

```
def custom_loss(y_actual,y_pred):   
dataset_whole=pd.read_sql("select * from Records", con=db)
dataset_features_only=dataset_whole.drop(['label'],axis=1)

dataset_whole_np=dataset_whole.values
dataset_whole_tf=tf.constant(dataset_whole_np)

dataset_features_np=dataset_features_only.values
dataset_features_tf=tf.constant(dataset_features_np)


index=tf.where(tf.equal(dataset_features_tf, y_actual))
row=dataset_whole_tf[index,:]

label=row['label']

return ((y_actual-y_pred)-tf.Variable(label,tf.float64))**
```

I see this error message in the *row=dataset_whole_tf[index,:]* line:

```
ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 2 and 0 From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for 'loss/dense_7_loss/strided_slice/stack_1' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [?,2], [].
```

Comment: ```label = row['label']``` isn't going to work. You can treat a tensor as a dictionary, AFAIK. I suggest that you determine label when you generate the data and that you pass it to the model as a separate output. You can then do a custom loss that operates on the 3 values.

Comment: The first two values are automatically passed to the loss function. I don't know where to pass the third value?

Comment: The suggestion is to create a multiple output model. You can output the same prediction twice to the model and pass as model targets both y_actual and y_label. You then need to build a loss function that looks at model.targets in order to retrieve these values.